# Is there any more than 25 event parameters and 25 user properties in firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I read on firebase analytics that with each event we can add maximum of 25 Parameters and 25 user properties .Is there any way/solution in case I need to pass more number of parameters to each firebase event